# Facebook backend login

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have been using this same code for so.  I tried to use it and it will not let me connect.  The front-end javascript one works and my app ids and all that match.  Since i want to log in the user i do back end verification (as any sane person would) and in verifyfacebook.php (the stuff your looking at) all the includes are there and i verified that FACEBOOK_APP_ID and SECRET both are correct and they echo out with their values.

I just do not understand what is going on!
Anyone see anything i am just missing?

```
try {
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID,
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $session = $facebook->getSession();

    $fbme = null;

    // Session based graph API call.
    if ($session) {
        try {
            $uid = $facebook->getUser();
            $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $f) {
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

---

I just tried to simply the example  and it still wont work.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID,
  'cookies' => true
));

// Get User ID
$uid = $facebook->getUser();

echo $uid;
```

It echos '0'

Comment: Are you using v2.x? Try using `3.0.0` and take a look at [examples](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php). Not sure why but 2.x stopped working for me, upgrading to 3.0.0. helped me out. And make sure to output values and exceptions to see what is going on.

Comment: I did do output on errors but it seems sessions is just null...  Ill try this 3.0.  Ill let you know if you should put it as an answer and ill give you te green check.

Comment: Ok so i tried all of this (sorry got distracted by roommate + halo) and it still does not get the user... which is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cookie` parameter is no longer used with 3.0.x. Below code did not work until I have removed all cookies, including session ones. `redirect_uri` is optional, just make sure you get redirected to the same page this code is executed.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ( $user )
{
    echo sprintf(
        '<a href="%s">Logout</a>',
         $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
            'redirect_uri' => URL,
         ))
    );
}
else
{
    echo sprintf(
        '<a href="%s">Login</a>',
         $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'redirect_uri' => URL,
            'scope'        => SCOPE,
         ))
    );
}

if ( $user )
{
    try
    {
        print_r($facebook->api('/me');
    }
    catch ( FacebookApiException $e )
    {
        print_r($e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This post should help:

```
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/
```

Try and implement the code as is, then once you get it working you can customise it to your needs.