# How to verify user login when using Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've already gone through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223226/javascript-sdk-automatically-login), but my question is different. I am unsure of how can javascript login be sure and how can some-else not login into others account.

According to the [getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart) `FB.authResponse` is called when the login is successful, but in the client's side of course.

Then we can get the `userId` & `accessToken` out of the response, we can also make call to `/me` to get more information. In order to put that user into session, all this info about successfull javascript login has to be sent to the server and this is where I get confused.
After all it's HTTP, every other request is different and can be replicated.

May be it's just that I'm confused, about how someone can't hack and immitate any other users' facebook id to login into his account.

For e.g. after the authentication is success, I make an ajax call to my server providing 
the fb-user-id and then I match it with the database and put the appropriate user in the session, but not since this is fb-user-id is not verified again in the back-end (or is it verified?, I didn't found anything though about it) that this particular user is the one who actually signed up in my application, then a same login request with someone else's fb-user-id can be made to login into his account.

I'm sure, I'm not the first one to have this confusion. Please help to clear this confusion, as I've read the docs many times now, but still unable to figure out why can't someone else login into someone else's account.

*EDIT*
I found this [`similar question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868590/facebook-backend-login) but the guy here doesn't answer how he verified backend login or may be I was unable to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to :

[How to securely authorize a user via Facebook's Javascript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186146/how-to-securely-authorize-a-user-via-facebooks-javascript-sdk)

Send the signed_request field to your server, which is being received in the `authResponse` using the javascript sdk

Then in the server-side, the following procedure as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games) has to be followed for verfication :

Once you have captured the signed request, you need to perform three steps:

1. Split the signed request into two parts delineated by a '.' character (eg. 238fsdfsd.oijdoifjsidf899)
2. Decode the first part - the encoded signature - from base64url
3. Decode the second part - the 'payload' - from base64url and then decode the resultant JSON object

Here is an example in PHP:

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  $secret = "appsecret"; // Use your app secret here

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  // confirm the signature
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

This will produce a JSON object that looks something like this:

```
{
   "oauth_token": "{user-access-token}",
   "algorithm": "HMAC-SHA256",
   "expires": 1291840400,
   "issued_at": 1291836800,
   "user_id": "218471"
}
```

After getting the user_id, that particular user can be put in session, although there needs to be other checks for proper authorization.

As a second check, the `issued_at` can be checked to see if it's not more than 10 mins old.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186146/how-to-securely-authorize-a-user-via-facebooks-javascript-sdk).

> However, there may be scenarios where your app_secret may be
>   compromised. To take care of this case, you should follow step #3, as
>   the exchange of code for access_token can happen only once and within
>   10 mins of it's issue. If the user doesn't have an account with your
>   site, then you anyway need step #3 to use the access_token for
>   retrieving other necessary user data, like name, email, etc from FB.

In order to refresh token the following call can be made from your server

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)

Answer (score 0):

When making a graph API call you need an access_token that is unique to an user and an app.
When query a call concerning a user-id and just manipulate it, the access-token you are using belongs to the original user and Facebook API just returns the information the manipulated id may get. This may be different if the manipulated user is a friend of the original or not.

Simplified:
Your user logs in at your website and accepts your scope params.
Now Facebook returns a user-id and an user access_token that is valid just to this user and your one app.

Most graph calls now needs a user-id and an access_token. If you do an update request for example on the users friend lists and the access_token does belong to the user, graph api will return an error.

It you store the access_token on your server and send it to your server via HTTP-Request / AJAX and not via https, a man in the middle could catch the access-token and abuse it.

Comment: if the man-in-middle can use it, so then how can I verify the logged in user without sending the user-id & access-token ? Secondly, which api call should I make to verify the user login ? Thirdly, I believe just by having user-id & token by the middle-man won't help, app-secret is also required for exploitation.

Comment: Actually you just need an access-token. Try this: Get an access-token from your account in graph explorer and copy your access-token behind this url:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. The link also doesn't work returns error.

Comment: That is again about the client-side, `FB.api('/me...` is I believe, what you're referring to.